# For await of returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, http, for-loop

I am attempting to take a JS object received from a HTTP request to Binance's testnet API and use a for await of to loop through the "balances" array to find the asset "BTC", then store that the "free" value of that asset to a variable.

However, this isn't completely evident in my code as I haven't been able to sucsessfully loop through them yet. I initially tried a simple "for" loop, and the app would close immediately after being run with no error code.

I am receiving the response from the request successfully, and have included the response below. However, my problem is with my method of looping through it.

When running the app, I receive all 6 entries of the array in the console however only as "undefined". Any help would be appreciated.

```js
async function getBalance() {
    try {
      const accountInfo = await client2.accountInfo()
    let balance;
    for await(balance of accountInfo.balances) {
          console.log(accountInfo.balances);
     }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

}
```

Here is the object I am attempting to loop through:

```js
{
  makerCommission: 0,
  takerCommission: 0,
  buyerCommission: 0,
  sellerCommission: 0,
  canTrade: true,
  canWithdraw: false,
  canDeposit: false,
  updateTime: 1619139652021,
  accountType: 'SPOT',
  balances: [
    { asset: 'BTC', free: '0.00000000', locked: '0.00000000' },
    { asset: 'ETH', free: '0.00000000', locked: '0.00000000' },
    { asset: 'LTC', free: '0.00000000', locked: '0.00000000' },
    { asset: 'TRX', free: '0.00000000', locked: '0.00000000' },
    { asset: 'USDT', free: '0.00000000', locked: '0.00000000' },
    { asset: 'XRP', free: '0.00000000', locked: '0.00000000' },
  ],
  permissions: [ 'SPOT' ]
}
```

```
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined
```

Comment: do `console.log( balance);`

Comment: @MisterJojo This worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

### Better to use forEach for Array

```
const balancesArray = accountInfo.balances;
balancesArray.forEach((balance) => {
   console.log(balance);
}
```